# Magento layout block

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, magento-layout-xml

i changed the images directly in the coding of the home page in the panel
and now its showing on the home page only before doing this it was showing on every product page any help will be appreciated.

Home Page - Screenshot
[image]

Product page - Screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in homepage you have used 2columns-left layout and for product detail page 2columns-right layout, so you have to check into both layout's phtml file and check if anything(e.g. cms-block) missing for product detail page.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is cms block which are calling on different positions first find block id for this and from admin disabled that block if you want to remove it thanks